# Angular Firestore (angularfire2) - Pull all "comments" that match a "photo" id

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

No idea how to properly "ask" this. I think in MySQL it was called "Joining" or something like that.

I have a collection called "Photos". I want the ability to add "Comments" to a photo. Those "Comments" will be stored in another collection. The structure for a comment his like this:

- comment (string)
- date (string - when was this posted)
- photoId (the ID of the photo this comment belongs to).

I have an Angular page that already is displaying info about a Photo. Now I want to display the comments for that photo. How can I pull only the comments that belong to that photo??

Also, I want this to be asyc because I will have the ability to add a new comment "on the fly".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just query your `comments` collection like so:

```
...
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
    afs.collection('comments', ref => ref.where('photoId','==', this.idOfPhotoYouAreDisplaying)).valueChanges()
}
...
```

if you want to check for `null` in the template you can assign the result to a variable (eg `comments`):

```
comments: Comment[];
comments$: Observable<Comment[]>;

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { 

    this.comments$ = this.db.collection(config.collection_comments, ref => ref.where('photoId', '==', this.photoId))
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(actions => {
                return actions.map(a => {
                    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Comment;
                    const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                    return { id, ...data };
                });
            }));
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.comments$.subscribe(c => this.comments == c);
}
```

Now in your template you can check on `comments`:

```
<div *ngIf="comments">
    <div *ngFor="let comment of comments">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note 1:**
You don't have to assign it to a variable. You can check with the `async` pipe in `ngIf`, but when you loop over your comments, again with `async` you create a second subscription, which will cause you're query to execute twice.

**Note 2:**
Using the `async` pipe handles the unsubscription of your observable. When subscribing in the component you need to handle this yourself. (Multiple ways to do this)

Comment: I havn't tried this yet but the "where" seems to do what I want. Thank You!

Comment: hey Tim. I get into a different problem. If the "query" returns ... null... I get lot's of errors. Do you have any suggestions on how to deal with this? If it's null, then set a boolean to false.

My current query looks like this:

this.db
      .collection(config.collection_comments,
          ref => ref.where('photoId', '==', this.photoId))
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Comment;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;

          return {id, ...data};
        });
      }));

Comment: Blah. I hate how this stackoverflow comments system is working.

Basically, I am able to display my comments on images that HAVE comments. On images that don't have comments I get a lot of errors in the console log, which makes total sense because it's returning nothing.

Comment: Actually nvm. My "lots of errors" were because I was doing a doDate() on a "null" thing.

I'm still however curious how can I detect if my db is returning null so I can use ngIf to display a "No Comments" template.